# A calculator in C without #include

Tags: c, console, io

I made a calculator in C without #include. Now, I want to make my code shorter and better. But I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);
double pow(double x, double y);

int main()
{
    do
    {
        double num1;
        double a, b = 1;
        char ch1;
        float r;
        scanf("%lf", &num1);
        printf("\ta - Factorial\n\tb - Continue\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch1);
        switch (ch1)
        {
            case 'a':
                for (a = 1; a <= num1; a++)
                {
                    b = b * a;
                }
                if (b < 500000001 & num1 > 0)
                {
                    printf("%f\n", b);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (b > 500000000)
                    {
                        printf("Number is Big\n");
                    }
                    if (num1 < 1)
                    {
                        printf("Number is Small\n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'b':
                double num2;
                char ch2;
                scanf("%lf", &num2);
                printf("\ta - Add\n\tb - Substract\n\tc - Multiply\n\td - Divide\n\te - Power\n\tf - Radical\n");
                scanf(" %c", &ch2);
                switch (ch2)
                {
                    case 'a':
                        r = num1 + num2;
                        if (num1 + num2 < 500000001 & num1 + num2 > -500000001 & num1 - num2 < 500000001 & num2 - num1 < 500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf + %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else if (num1 + num2 > 500000000)
                        {
                            printf("Number is Big\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        r = num1 - num2;
                        if (num1 + num2 < 500000001 & num1 + num2 > -500000001 & num1 - num2 < 500000001 & num2 - num1 < 500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf - %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else if (num1 + num2 > 500000000)
                        {
                            printf("Number is Big\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        r = num1 * num2;
                        if (num1 * num2 < 500000001 & num1 * num2 > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf * %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (num1 * num2 > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 * num2 < -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        r = num1 / num2;
                        if (num1 * num2 < 500000001 & num1 * num2 > -500000001 && num2 > 0 | num1 == 0 & num2 != 0)
                        {
                            printf("%lf / %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (num1 * num2 > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 * num2 < -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 > 0 & num2 == 0 | num1 == 0 & num2 == 0)
                            {
                                printf("Undefined\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        r = pow(num1, num2);
                        if (pow(num1, num2) < 500000001 & pow(num1, num2) > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf ^ %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                    case 'f':
                        r = pow(num1, 1 / num2);
                        if (pow(num1, num2) < 500000001 & pow(num1, num2) > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf √ %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("Invalid\n");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: Two questions, if I may: Why avoid `#include` and what is the deal with 500000000 and similar randomly sprinkled throughout the code?

Comment: Another question: why is `scanf()` `extern` but `printf()` and `pow()` aren't?

Comment: Unless this is for some "code golf" challenge, then shorter is not necessarily better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a calculator in C without #include. Now, I want to make my code shorter and better.

**To make the code *better***

Focus on clarity and not shortness.

Use `#include<>`s.

Check return values from input functions.

Replace naked magic numbers:

```
// if (b > 500000000)
// if (num1 * num2 < 500000001 

#define LIMIT 500000000
...
if (b > LIMIT)
if (num1 * num2 <= LIMIT  /* not quite the same with FP math, but certainly matches intent */
```

Use `&&` instead of `&` for logical tests.

Remove redundant code

```
// r = num1 + num2;
// if (num1 + num2 < 500000001 & num1 + num2 > -500000001 & num1 - num2 < 500000001 & num2 - num1 < 500000001)

r = num1 + num2;
if (r <= LIMIT && r >= -LIMIT)
```

Even better, consider a helper function for the range test.

```
r = num1 + num2;
if (in_range(r))
```

More informative to print `double` with `"%g"` than `"%f"`.

Review potential bug in `case 'd':`.  Why `if (num1 * num2` instead of `if (num1 / num2`?

Prevent division by 0.

Very unclear why code uses `float r;` with its differing precision and range versus `double r;` here.

---

**To make shorter**

Keep in mind shorter is not certainly better.

Drop `extern` from  `extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);`

Drop identifiers in prototypes: `int scanf(const char *, ...);`

Use `#include<>`s, less text in this .c file than adding your own prototypes.

Replace naked magic numbers.

`b = b * a;` --> `b *= a;`

Indent less.  Use a tighter format: e.g.:

```
//            if (num1 < 1)
//                {
//                   printf("Number is Small\n");
//                }

if (num1 < 1) printf("Number is Small\n");
```

Replace simply prints

```
// printf("Number is Small\n");
puts("Number is Small");
```

Replace `do`

```
//do
//  {
//  } while (1);

for (;;) { }
```

`l` not needed.

```
//printf("%lf - %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
printf("%f - %f = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
```

Declare compare types on same line

```
    // double num1;
    // double a, b = 1;
    double num1, a, b = 1;
```

I'd re-use code per `case`

```
void print_result(double a, double b, double r, char op) {
  if (r >= -LIMIT && r <= LIMIT) {
    printf("%g %c %g = %g\n", num1, op, num2, r);
  } else {
    printf("Number is Big\n");
  }
}

    case 'a': print_result(a, b, a+b, '+'); break;
    case 'b': print_result(a, b, a-b, '-'); break;
    case 'c': print_result(a, b, a*b, '*'); break;
    ....
```

Look to [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Unless I mistake your intent, _Focus on clarity and not shortness_ and _Look to code golf_ seem at odds?

Comment: @Reinderien Yes, parts of OP's 2 goals of "make the code better" are at odds with "To make shorter".  With real world coding, it is striking a balance (mostly in favor of better) than making it shorter.